# Color filling effect in Unity - Rendering Fluid Simulation on a Cube in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, shader, game-physics, game-engine

Hello Unity community,

I'm currently working on a game project that involves a color filling effect in a transparent 3D mesh, similar to ink dispersing in water. I'm facing some challenges in implementing this effect and would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.

Here's a brief overview of the problem:

Gameplay Understanding: The player interacts with a transparent cube by injecting a specific color into it. The color should gradually spread within the cube, simulating a diffusion effect, until the entire cube is filled.

Problem Description: I've set up the transparent cube using a shader graph and created a material with the appropriate shader. I also have a ColorInjector script that handles injecting the color based on player input. However, I'm struggling with the following components of the color filling effect:
link to a similar effect:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5tc5DlNTVo&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.unity.com%2F&embeds_referring_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.unity.com&feature=emb_imp_woyt
Color Dispersion: I'm unsure how to simulate the gradual spread of color within the cube. I've tried different approaches, including Unity's Particle System, but I haven't achieved the desired effect yet.

Visualizing the Color: I'm not sure how to create a custom shader that properly samples the 3D texture and applies the color to the cube's fragments.

Color Filling Completion: I need to implement a check to determine when all the voxels in the 3D texture are filled, indicating that the color filling is complete.
If anyone has experience or knowledge in implementing similar color filling effects or can offer guidance, I would greatly appreciate your input. Any code snippets, references, or suggestions for alternative approaches would be incredibly helpful.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance. I'm eager to learn and overcome this challenge to enhance my game development skills.

Best regards,
Muftah.

I have tried implementing the color dispersion using Unity's Particle System, but the effect is not working as expected.
I created a transparent cube using a shader graph and assigned it a material with the appropriate shader. Additionally, I implemented a ColorInjector script that handles injecting the color into the cube based on player input. To achieve the color dispersion effect, I used Unity's Particle System and configured it to emit particles within the cube's volume.
I expected the particles emitted by the Particle System to disperse and gradually fill the entire cube with the injected color. The color should spread smoothly and convincingly within the cube, simulating a diffusion effect (see the video above).
Unfortunately, the color dispersion effect is not working as expected.
I have double-checked the shader and material setup, and they seem to be working correctly.
The ColorInjector script successfully injects the color into the cube at the specified point.
I have experimented with different approaches like I tried to implement a GPU version of Stable Fluids by Jos Stam in Unity3D, and I need to render the simulation on a cube's surface and gradually fill the cube with a specific color based on the fluid simulation this approach involves rendering the simulation on a 2D texture, which I then apply to a the cube texture. and it did not work. However, I'm encountering issues in applying the fluid effect on the cube and having the cube gradually fill up with the color.

**Because it's a simple mobile game, I'm aware that there's a very simple visual trick to achieve that goal, so I think you can help me.**